# How to remove href from gridview cells?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a button click that will generate the text from gridview cells. But I want to remove the href tag when it get the text. How can I do it? Trying to do .atrributes.remove("href) but can't get it to save to a arraylist

```
protected void Button_Example_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow s in GridView_Staff.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox CheckBox_Staff = (s.FindControl("CheckBox_Staff") as CheckBox);
            if (CheckBox_Staff.Checked == true)
            {
                s.Cells[2].Attributes.Remove("href");
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + s.Cells[2].Text + "');</script>");
            }
        }


    }
```

s.Cells[2].Text contains:

```
<a href="example.com">Example A</a>
```

Comment: Can you post the code with the `.attributes.remove()` line in it, so we can see the full example of what you've tried, and the results you are getting?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: You have to show also the aspx code since it's not clear if you're using real controls in TemplateFields or plain BoundFields.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I was last using webforms and `GridView`, but to my eye it looks as though you are calling `.Attributes.Remove()` on the `Cell` object itself (`.Cells[2]`). But I would have thought that the anchor tag was *inside* the cell?

Would it not be more like this (excuse the pseudo-code):

```
var Anchor = s.Cells[2].FindControl("TheAnchor") as AnchorTag;

Anchor.Attributes.Remove("href");

Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Anchor.Text + "');</script>");
```

Or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to remove the href attribute like this:

```
protected void Button_Example_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow s in GridView_Staff.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox_Staff = (s.FindControl("CheckBox_Staff") as CheckBox);
        if (CheckBox_Staff.Checked == true)
        {
            string text = s.Cells[2].Text;
            string pattern =  @"(?<=<[^<>]+)\s+(?:href)\s*=\s*([""']).*?\1";

            text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            s.Cells[2].Text = text;

            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + s.Cells[2].Text + "');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```